# How can I split my Ada program into separate files

Tags: ada

I have a problem; I have to do the project and I do not know how to split the code into parts. I need to separate the "task body Buffer" (it is on the end) part from the rest. I am enclosing a design template which I have already done. Everything works, but I need help with the separation, please. Thank you very much for any help.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;
procedure Simulation is
   Number_Of_Products: constant Integer := 5;
   Number_Of_Assemblies: constant Integer := 3;
   Number_Of_Consumers: constant Integer := 2;
   subtype Production_Time_Range is Integer range 3 .. 6;
   subtype Consumption_Time_Range is Integer range 4 .. 8;
   subtype Product_Type is Integer range 1 .. Number_Of_Products;
   subtype Assembly_Type is Integer range 1 .. Number_Of_Assemblies;
   subtype Consumer_Type is Integer range 1 .. Number_Of_Consumers;
   Product_Name: constant array (Product_Type) of String(1 .. 8)
     := ("Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4", "Product5");
   Assembly_Name: constant array (Assembly_Type) of String(1 .. 9)
     := ("Assembly1", "Assembly2", "Assembly3");
   package Random_Consumption is new
     Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Consumption_Time_Range);
   package Random_Assembly is new
     Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Assembly_Type);
   type My_Str is new String(1 ..256);

   -- Producer produces determined product
   task type Producer is
      -- Give the Producer an identity, i.e. the product type
      entry Start(Product: in Product_Type; Production_Time: in Integer);
   end Producer;

   -- Consumer gets an arbitrary assembly of several products from the buffer
   task type Consumer is
      -- Give the Consumer an identity
      entry Start(Consumer_Number: in Consumer_Type;
            Consumption_Time: in Integer);
   end Consumer;

   -- In the Buffer, products are assemblied into an assembly
   task type Buffer is
      -- Accept a product to the storage provided there is a room for it
      entry Take(Product: in Product_Type; Number: in Integer);
      -- Deliver an assembly provided there are enough products for it
      entry Deliver(Assembly: in Assembly_Type; Number: out Integer);
   end Buffer;

   P: array ( 1 .. Number_Of_Products ) of Producer;
   K: array ( 1 .. Number_Of_Consumers ) of Consumer;
   B: Buffer;

   task body Producer is
      package Random_Production is new
    Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Production_Time_Range);
      G: Random_Production.Generator;   --  generator liczb losowych
      Product_Type_Number: Integer;
      Product_Number: Integer;
      Production: Integer;
   begin
      accept Start(Product: in Product_Type; Production_Time: in Integer) do
     Random_Production.Reset(G);    --  start random number generator
     Product_Number := 1;
     Product_Type_Number := Product;
     Production := Production_Time;
      end Start;
      Put_Line("Started producer of " & Product_Name(Product_Type_Number));
      loop
     delay Duration(Random_Production.Random(G)); --  symuluj produkcjÄ
     Put_Line("Produced product " & Product_Name(Product_Type_Number)
            & " number "  & Integer'Image(Product_Number));
     -- Accept for storage
     B.Take(Product_Type_Number, Product_Number);
     Product_Number := Product_Number + 1;
      end loop;
   end Producer;

   task body Consumer is
      G: Random_Consumption.Generator;  --  random number generator (time)
      G2: Random_Assembly.Generator;    --  also (assemblies)
      Consumer_Nb: Consumer_Type;
      Assembly_Number: Integer;
      Consumption: Integer;
      Assembly_Type: Integer;
      Consumer_Name: constant array (1 .. Number_Of_Consumers)
    of String(1 .. 9)
    := ("Consumer1", "Consumer2");
   begin
      accept Start(Consumer_Number: in Consumer_Type;
             Consumption_Time: in Integer) do
     Random_Consumption.Reset(G);   --  ustaw generator
     Random_Assembly.Reset(G2); --  teÅ¼
     Consumer_Nb := Consumer_Number;
     Consumption := Consumption_Time;
      end Start;
      Put_Line("Started consumer " & Consumer_Name(Consumer_Nb));
      loop
     delay Duration(Random_Consumption.Random(G)); --  simulate consumption
     Assembly_Type := Random_Assembly.Random(G2);
     -- take an assembly for consumption
     B.Deliver(Assembly_Type, Assembly_Number);
     Put_Line(Consumer_Name(Consumer_Nb) & ": taken assembly " &
            Assembly_Name(Assembly_Type) & " number " &
            Integer'Image(Assembly_Number));
      end loop;
   end Consumer;

   task body Buffer is
      Storage_Capacity: constant Integer := 30;
      type Storage_type is array (Product_Type) of Integer;
      Storage: Storage_type
    := (0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      Assembly_Content: array(Assembly_Type, Product_Type) of Integer
    := ((2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
        (2, 2, 0, 1, 0),
        (1, 1, 2, 0, 1));
      Max_Assembly_Content: array(Product_Type) of Integer;
      Assembly_Number: array(Assembly_Type) of Integer
    := (1, 1, 1);
      In_Storage: Integer := 0;

      procedure Setup_Variables is
      begin
     for W in Product_Type loop
        Max_Assembly_Content(W) := 0;
        for Z in Assembly_Type loop
           if Assembly_Content(Z, W) > Max_Assembly_Content(W) then
          Max_Assembly_Content(W) := Assembly_Content(Z, W);
           end if;
        end loop;
     end loop;
      end Setup_Variables;

      function Can_Accept(Product: Product_Type) return Boolean is
     Free: Integer;     --  free room in the storage
     -- how many products are for production of arbitrary assembly
     Lacking: array(Product_Type) of Integer;
     -- how much room is needed in storage to produce arbitrary assembly
     Lacking_room: Integer;
     MP: Boolean;           --  can accept
      begin
     if In_Storage >= Storage_Capacity then
        return False;
     end if;
     -- There is free room in the storage
     Free := Storage_Capacity - In_Storage;
     MP := True;
     for W in Product_Type loop
        if Storage(W) < Max_Assembly_Content(W) then
           MP := False;
        end if;
     end loop;
     if MP then
        return True;        --  storage has products for arbitrary
                        --  assembly
     end if;
     if Integer'Max(0, Max_Assembly_Content(Product) - Storage(Product)) > 0 then
        -- exactly this product lacks
        return True;
     end if;
     Lacking_room := 1;         --  insert current product
     for W in Product_Type loop
        Lacking(W) := Integer'Max(0, Max_Assembly_Content(W) - Storage(W));
        Lacking_room := Lacking_room + Lacking(W);
     end loop;
     if Free >= Lacking_room then
        -- there is enough room in storage for arbitrary assembly
        return True;
     else
        -- no room for this product
        return False;
     end if;
      end Can_Accept;

      function Can_Deliver(Assembly: Assembly_Type) return Boolean is
      begin
     for W in Product_Type loop
        if Storage(W) < Assembly_Content(Assembly, W) then
           return False;
        end if;
     end loop;
     return True;
      end Can_Deliver;

      procedure Storage_Contents is
      begin
     for W in Product_Type loop
        Put_Line("Storage contents: " & Integer'Image(Storage(W)) & " "
               & Product_Name(W));
     end loop;
      end Storage_Contents;

   begin
      Put_Line("Buffer started");
      Setup_Variables;
      loop
     accept Take(Product: in Product_Type; Number: in Integer) do
       if Can_Accept(Product) then
          Put_Line("Accepted product " & Product_Name(Product) & " number " &
        Integer'Image(Number));
          Storage(Product) := Storage(Product) + 1;
          In_Storage := In_Storage + 1;
       else
          Put_Line("Rejected product " & Product_Name(Product) & " number " &
            Integer'Image(Number));
       end if;
     end Take;
     Storage_Contents;
     accept Deliver(Assembly: in Assembly_Type; Number: out Integer) do
        if Can_Deliver(Assembly) then
           Put_Line("Delivered assembly " & Assembly_Name(Assembly) & " number " &
              Integer'Image(Assembly_Number(Assembly)));
           for W in Product_Type loop
          Storage(W) := Storage(W) - Assembly_Content(Assembly, W);
          In_Storage := In_Storage - Assembly_Content(Assembly, W);
           end loop;
           Number := Assembly_Number(Assembly);
           Assembly_Number(Assembly) := Assembly_Number(Assembly) + 1;
        else
           Put_Line("Lacking products for assembly " & Assembly_Name(Assembly));
           Number := 0;
        end if;
     end Deliver;
     Storage_Contents;
      end loop;
   end Buffer;

begin
   for I in 1 .. Number_Of_Products loop
      P(I).Start(I, 10);
   end loop;
   for J in 1 .. Number_Of_Consumers loop
      K(J).Start(J,12);
   end loop;
end Simulation;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should learn about Ada packages ([Introduction to packages](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/intro/part4/#package)) . I see at least two broad classifications of concepts in your code: products/assemblies and a simulated manufacturing line (producers and consumers). 
Separate the definitions of products and assemblies into one package and the task definitions (the factory workings) into another package.

Edit:
I have taken the time to partition your code. The partitioning reveals opportunities for your code to be better organized. For instance, I changed the task type Buffer into a task named Buffer. Your code only needed one instance of this task.

Packages:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Notice that there is no relationship between products and
-- assemblies in the data definitions. That relationship is established
-- in the Buffer task type defined in the Tasks package;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

package Products_Assemblies is
   Number_Of_Products: constant Integer := 5;
   Number_Of_Assemblies: constant Integer := 3;
   subtype Product_Type is Integer range 1 .. Number_Of_Products;
   subtype Assembly_Type is Integer range 1 .. Number_Of_Assemblies;
   Product_Name: constant array (Product_Type) of String(1 .. 8)
     := ("Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4", "Product5");
   Assembly_Name: constant array (Assembly_Type) of String(1 .. 9)
     := ("Assembly1", "Assembly2", "Assembly3");
end Products_Assemblies;
```

Notice that this package does not map a relationship between products and assemblies. Such relationships are often best established as data structures. Second, Product type could more clearly be implemented as an enumeration type

```
type Product_Type is (Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product5);
```

Similarly Assembly_Type could be implemented as

```
type Assembly_Type is (Assembly1, Assembly2, Assembly3);
```

The enumeration name values of an enumeration type can be displayed as a string using the 'Image attribute.

Tasks package specification:
with products_assemblies; use Products_Assemblies;

```
package Tasks is
   Number_Of_Consumers  : constant Integer := 2;

   subtype Consumer_Type is Integer range 1 .. Number_Of_Consumers;


   -- Producer produces determined product
   task type Producer is
      -- Give the Producer an identity, i.e. the product type
      entry Start (Product : in Product_Type; Production_Time : in Integer);
   end Producer;

   -- Consumer gets an arbitrary assembly of several products from the buffer
   task type Consumer is
      -- Give the Consumer an identity
      entry Start (Consumer_Number : in Consumer_Type; Consumption_Time : in Integer);
   end Consumer;

   -- In the Buffer, products are assemblied into an assembly
   task Buffer is
      -- Accept a product to the storage provided there is a room for it
      entry Take (Product : in Product_Type; Number : in Integer);
      -- Deliver an assembly provided there are enough products for it
      entry Deliver (Assembly : in Assembly_Type; Number : out Integer);
   end Buffer;
end Tasks;
```

Note that this is where I changed Buffer from a task type to a task.

```
Task package body:
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

package body tasks is

   subtype Production_Time_Range is Integer range 3 .. 6;

   subtype Consumption_Time_Range is Integer range 4 .. 8;

   package Random_Consumption is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random
     (Consumption_Time_Range);

   package Random_Assembly is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Assembly_Type);
   type My_Str is new String (1 .. 256);

   task body Producer is
      package Random_Production is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random
        (Production_Time_Range);
      G : Random_Production.Generator;   --  generator liczb losowych
      Product_Type_Number : Integer;
      Product_Number      : Integer;
      Production          : Integer;
   begin
      accept Start (Product : in Product_Type; Production_Time : in Integer) do
         Random_Production.Reset (G);    --  start random number generator
         Product_Number      := 1;
         Product_Type_Number := Product;
         Production          := Production_Time;
      end Start;
      Put_Line ("Started producer of " & Product_Name (Product_Type_Number));
      loop
         delay Duration (Random_Production.Random (G)); --  symuluj produkcjÄ
         Put_Line
           ("Produced product " & Product_Name (Product_Type_Number) &
              " number " & Integer'Image (Product_Number));
         -- Accept for storage
         Buffer.Take (Product_Type_Number, Product_Number);
         Product_Number := Product_Number + 1;
      end loop;
   end Producer;

   task body Consumer is
      G                                             : Random_Consumption.Generator;  --  random number generator (time)
      G2                                            : Random_Assembly.Generator;    --  also (assemblies)
      Consumer_Nb                                   : Consumer_Type;
      Assembly_Number                               : Integer;
      Consumption                                   : Integer;
      Assembly_Type                                 : Integer;
      Consumer_Name                                 : constant array
        (1 .. Number_Of_Consumers) of String (1 .. 9) :=
        ("Consumer1", "Consumer2");
   begin
      accept Start (Consumer_Number : in Consumer_Type;
                    Consumption_Time           : in Integer) do
         Random_Consumption.Reset (G);   --  ustaw generator
         Random_Assembly.Reset (G2); --  teÅ¼
         Consumer_Nb := Consumer_Number;
         Consumption := Consumption_Time;
      end Start;
      Put_Line ("Started consumer " & Consumer_Name (Consumer_Nb));
      loop
         delay Duration
           (Random_Consumption.Random (G)); --  simulate consumption
         Assembly_Type := Random_Assembly.Random (G2);
         -- take an assembly for consumption
         Buffer.Deliver (Assembly_Type, Assembly_Number);
         Put_Line
           (Consumer_Name (Consumer_Nb) & ": taken assembly " &
              Assembly_Name (Assembly_Type) & " number " &
              Integer'Image (Assembly_Number));
      end loop;
   end Consumer;

   task body Buffer is
      Storage_Capacity : constant Integer := 30;
      type Storage_type is array (Product_Type) of Integer;
      Storage          : Storage_type := (0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      Assembly_Content : array (Assembly_Type, Product_Type) of Integer :=
        ((2, 1, 2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 2, 0, 1));
      Max_Assembly_Content : array (Product_Type) of Integer;
      Assembly_Number      : array (Assembly_Type) of Integer := (1, 1, 1);
      In_Storage           : Integer                          := 0;

      procedure Setup_Variables is
      begin
         for W in Product_Type loop
            Max_Assembly_Content (W) := 0;
            for Z in Assembly_Type loop
               if Assembly_Content (Z, W) > Max_Assembly_Content (W) then
                  Max_Assembly_Content (W) := Assembly_Content (Z, W);
               end if;
            end loop;
         end loop;
      end Setup_Variables;

      function Can_Accept (Product : Product_Type) return Boolean is
         Free         : Integer;     --  free room in the storage
         -- how many products are for production of arbitrary assembly
         Lacking      : array (Product_Type) of Integer;
         -- how much room is needed in storage to produce arbitrary assembly
         Lacking_room : Integer;
         MP           : Boolean;           --  can accept
      begin
         if In_Storage >= Storage_Capacity then
            return False;
         end if;
         -- There is free room in the storage
         Free := Storage_Capacity - In_Storage;
         MP   := True;
         for W in Product_Type loop
            if Storage (W) < Max_Assembly_Content (W) then
               MP := False;
            end if;
         end loop;
         if MP then
            return True;        --  storage has products for arbitrary
            --  assembly
         end if;
         if Integer'Max (0,
                         Max_Assembly_Content (Product) - Storage (Product)) >
           0 then
            -- exactly this product lacks
            return True;
         end if;
         Lacking_room := 1;         --  insert current product
         for W in Product_Type loop
            Lacking (W) :=
              Integer'Max (0, Max_Assembly_Content (W) - Storage (W));
            Lacking_room := Lacking_room + Lacking (W);
         end loop;
         if Free >= Lacking_room then
            -- there is enough room in storage for arbitrary assembly
            return True;
         else
            -- no room for this product
            return False;
         end if;
      end Can_Accept;

      function Can_Deliver (Assembly : Assembly_Type) return Boolean is
      begin
         for W in Product_Type loop
            if Storage (W) < Assembly_Content (Assembly, W) then
               return False;
            end if;
         end loop;
         return True;
      end Can_Deliver;

      procedure Storage_Contents is
      begin
         for W in Product_Type loop
            Put_Line
              ("Storage contents: " & Integer'Image (Storage (W)) & " " &
                 Product_Name (W));
         end loop;
      end Storage_Contents;

   begin
      Put_Line ("Buffer started");
      Setup_Variables;
      loop
         accept Take (Product : in Product_Type; Number : in Integer) do
            if Can_Accept (Product) then
               Put_Line
                 ("Accepted product " & Product_Name (Product) & " number " &
                    Integer'Image (Number));
               Storage (Product) := Storage (Product) + 1;
               In_Storage        := In_Storage + 1;
            else
               Put_Line
                 ("Rejected product " & Product_Name (Product) & " number " &
                    Integer'Image (Number));
            end if;
         end Take;
         Storage_Contents;
         accept Deliver (Assembly : in Assembly_Type; Number : out Integer) do
            if Can_Deliver (Assembly) then
               Put_Line
                 ("Delivered assembly " & Assembly_Name (Assembly) &
                    " number " & Integer'Image (Assembly_Number (Assembly)));
               for W in Product_Type loop
                  Storage (W) := Storage (W) - Assembly_Content (Assembly, W);
                  In_Storage  := In_Storage - Assembly_Content (Assembly, W);
               end loop;
               Number                     := Assembly_Number (Assembly);
               Assembly_Number (Assembly) := Assembly_Number (Assembly) + 1;
            else
               Put_Line
                 ("Lacking products for assembly " & Assembly_Name (Assembly));
               Number := 0;
            end if;
         end Deliver;
         Storage_Contents;
      end loop;
   end Buffer;
end tasks;
```

Finally, I provided a "main" procedure to test the packages:

```
with Tasks; use Tasks;
with Products_Assemblies; use Products_Assemblies;

procedure Simulation_Main is
   P : array (1 .. Number_Of_Products) of Producer;
   K : array (1 .. Number_Of_Consumers) of Consumer;

begin
   for I in 1 .. Number_Of_Products loop
      P (I).Start (I, 10);
   end loop;
   for J in 1 .. Number_Of_Consumers loop
      K (J).Start (J, 12);
   end loop;
end Simulation_Main;
```

This version compiles without error and runs. There is no built-in way to terminate the simulation. You might want to consider providing a clean way to shut everything down. You may also want to review some of your design. For instance, the Production_Time parameter for the Start entry for the Producer task type is never used within the task. It is assigned to a local variable and then ignored.

Comment: yes, I've been fighting packages and there has always been some mistake. so many different combinations and always something did not fit. I've been looking for different pages but there are not many guides for this language. I concluded that one package should be a child but something still does not work.

Comment: thank you very much for help. I had to change the code a little bit, add exceptions and probably everything is fine.